# Android Studio 2.2.3 to 2.3 update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.3

I am trying to update Android Studio 2.2.3 to Android Studio 2.3 which is announced recently.

I have tried with **`Help -> Check for update`** in menu but its displaying dialog like:

[image]

I have currently **Android Studio 2.2.3**

**Edited:**

[image]

How do I update? Should I have to download new?

Comment: check if the stream is stable channel or not

Comment: please delete(move) configuration file of android studio from `C:/users/your_system_name/.AndroidStudio2.2.3` delete or move `.AndroidStudio2.2.3`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Follow the Steps:

1) Go to File -> Settings

2) Now Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates

3) Select the Stable Channel from the Dropdown of Automatically check updates for as shown in the below pic.

4) Apply and Ok

5) Restart and now Check for updates. It will work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ;) ;) Actually I had done this thing, I think problem is, I discarded dialog, when first time prompted for `Android Studio` update.

Comment: check my edited question, still getting same problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can check the stable channel or not

Go to

> File => Settings=>Now Appearance & Behavior => System Settings =>
>   Updates

Then make it as stable channel then press check now
[image]

**Edit**

> Please delete(move) configuration file of android studio from
>   C:/users/your_system_name/.AndroidStudio2.2.3 delete or move
>   .AndroidStudio2.2.3 and restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

Finally I cut/paste **.AndroidStudio2.2** folder from `C:\Users\Pratik` and started again **Android Studio.**

It will prompt you for **Android Studio Update Available.**

Comment: ha ha yeah. But I got solution today. :D